# Python regular expression: Getting string with certain pattern

Tags: python, regex

I need some help with regular expression in python. I have many files which, unfortunately, contains invaid xml: as below some 'img' tag is not closed.

```
<a href="a_url" class="url" target="_blank">
   <img ng-src=" {{getImageUrl('homeHelp64.jpg')}}" alt="?" width="16" height="16">
      Home
</a>
```

In Python what I would like to do is to find all such 'img' tags that are not closed and replace it with close tag like below ('/' before >):

```
<img ng-src=" {{getImageUrl('homeHelp64.jpg')}}" alt="?" width="16" height="16"/>
```

using the following pattern I can get all instances of img tag but i need to get only the ones that are not closed.

```
pattern = '(img.*?)>'
```

will appreciate your help in defining the pattern and how to replace the 'img' and close the xml tag at the end.

Comment: You are probably better off using an html/xml parser as this type of match is horrific in Regex.  For example, Regex doesn't understand quoted items (that may have contain `>`) or child elements

Comment: You might try `<img[^<>]*(?=(?<!/)>)` and replace with `\g<0>/` but you should read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) why that can be really tricky.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Thefourthbird using that pattern i do not get '>' at the end. is there a possibility to get it as well?

Comment: @JonathanTwite, I tried xml parsing first with since the xml is invalid I was getting error.

Comment: If there is a `>` it will put the `/` in front of it right? https://regex101.com/r/KYGD8D/1

Comment: @user1749707, if this is HTML, the image tag doesn't technically need closing so this is syntactically correct (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element)  If this is XHTML, then you are probably better served to parse it with an HTML to XHTML converter

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the problem correctly, I managed to write the required regular expression. By link, you can test the expression. Required flag - s

https://regex101.com/r/YctLzb/5/tests

```
\<(\w+)\s[^<>]+\>(?!.*\<\/\1\>)
```

Update:
this works without s flag and matches tags without attrs:
https://regex101.com/r/6nwHQP/1/tests

```
\<(\w+)(?:\s[^<>]+)?\>(?!(?:.|\n)*\<\/\1\>)
```

Comment: The links to that website are not very helpful. It's better to include the examples of what those patterns do and don't match here in your answer.